# Boolean property not triggering dependent observable trigger

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of "Option" objects. Each "Option" contains a "Name", "Description" and a "Selected" boolean field to indicate whether its been selected. I've created a template to render the Options and the page outputs fine with everything in place.

However, the trigger I created that should catch the change of state of the "Selected" field  doesnt seem to work. The "ajaxTrigger" dependent observable should trigger a call to the server if the options array changes in any way but this doesnt seem to be the case.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

JSON Data:

```
{
    "Name": "Add Helicopter Excursion",
    "Description": "Enjoy a holiday excursion",
    "Code": "HEL",
    "Selected": false
}, {
    "Name": "Add Scuba Diving",
    "Description": "Go on a scuba diving trip",
    "Code": "SCU",
    "Selected": false
}
```

View Model:

```
var viewModel = {
  // other view model properties removed for this example
  options: ko.observableArray(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Options))))
}

viewModel.ajaxTrigger = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    // other triggers removed for this example
    this.options();
    GetPrices();     
}, viewModel);
```

Template:

```html
<script id="OptionsTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected" />
    <span data-bind="text: Name"> </span> <span data-bind="text: Description"> </span>
  </li>
</script>
```

UI:

```html
<ul data-bind='template: {name: "OptionsTemplate", foreach: options}'></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

observableArrays only notify on changes to the array itself (items added/removed, array replaced entirely).  It will not trigger on changes to observables on the individual items.  If you wanted the dependentObservbale to trigger, then you would need to make `Selected` an observable and make sure that you access each item's `Selected` value in your dependentObservable.

Comment: Thanks. How do I make the Selected property an observable given that its a property that belongs to an item within am array?

Comment: There are a few ways that you could do it.  Probably easiest just to loop through your array prior to calling applyBindings and for each item create an observable set to the current value: `item.selected = ko.observable(item.selected);`

Comment: So thats something I do outside of the view model?

Comment: In this situation am I best off using the mapping plug-in?

Comment: OK, ive tried looping through the array as you suggest:             for(var item in viewModel.options()) {
alert(ko.toJSON(item));
item.Selected = ko.observable(item.Selected);
alert(ko.toJSON(item.Selected));
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);  -- The alerts are there to debug the contents of each item. I'd expect the first alert to show the properties for the option in JSON (Name, description, etc) but it just gives the index ("0", "1", "2", etc)

Comment: In your example, why do you need "ko.toJS(this.options)" when options is already a javascript object?

Comment: ko.toJS(this.options) is just a convenient way to subscribe to anything that is observable.  At the very least it would unwrap the options observableArray and if you made `Selected` an observable, then it would unwrap each item's `Selected` as well without you having to write a loop.